# How do I configure the update manager to sync daily unless connected on mobile broadband?

Tags: update-manager, mobile-broadband

My mobile internet provider limits network speed after 1Gb of transfer. Is it possible to prevent Ubuntu from checking for updates automatically if connected on mobile broadland ?

It would be fantastic if it only checked for updates daily when connected on wifi or ethernet, but never when connected on mobile broadland.

Comment: Just remove the **Connect automatically** option from Network manager under your mobile broadband. Though , using it for other purposes would need manual Enabling of connection.

Comment: Connect automatically option is not checked for mobile broadland. I'm already enabling it manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates) and this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/776374) the update manager should warn you if you're on mobile broadband and there are updates available.

However if you want to file a bug on having all that be automatic depending on what speed network you're on it sounds like a good idea for a wishlist bug report:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to prevent even the `apt-get update` part, while the bug deals with the `upgrade` part...

Comment: @izx is correct, I filled a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1039979 Thanks for your feedback !

Answer (score 1):

You can set **`Automatically check for Updates`** to **`Never`** in **Software sources** or you can access it in `Settings` option from Ubuntu Software Center.

So when using **Wifi** or **Ethernet** you can check for updates manually every-time thus preserving Bandwidth in Mobile Broadband.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It would be fantastic if it only checked for updates daily when connected on wifi or ethernet, but never when connected on mobile broadland.